# Glue Crawler Skips a Particular S3 Folder

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-glue

My S3 bucket is organised with this hierarchy, storing parquet file: `<folder-name>/year=<yyyy>/month=<mm>/day=<dd>/<filename>.parquet`

## Manual Fixation

For a particular date (i.e. a single parquet file), I do some manual fixation

- Downloaded the parquet file and read it as pandas DataFrame
- Updated some values, while the column remains unchanged
- Saved the pandas DataFrame back to parquet file with the same filename
- Uploaded it back to same S3 bucket sub-folder

**PS**: I seem to have deleted the parquet file on S3 once, leading to empty sub-folder.

Then, I re-run the Glue crawler, pointing `<folder-name>/`. Unfortunately, data of this particular date is missing in the Athena Table.

After the crawler is finished running, the notification is as follow

```
Crawler <my-table-name> completed and made the following changes: 0 tables created, 0 tables updated. See the tables created in database <my-databse-name>.
```

Is there anything I have mis-configured in my Glue crawler ? Thanks

#### Glue Crawler Config

- **Schema updates in the data store**: Update the table definition in the data catalog.
- **Inherit schema from table**: Update all new and existing partitions with metadata from the table.
- **Object deletion in the data store**: Delete tables and partitions from the data catalog.

### Crawler Log in CloudWatch

```
BENCHMARK : Running Start Crawl for Crawler <my-table-name>
BENCHMARK : Classification complete, writing results to database <my-database-name>
INFO : Crawler configured with Configuration
{
    "Version": 1,
    "CrawlerOutput": {
        "Partitions": {
            "AddOrUpdateBehavior": "InheritFromTable"
        }
    },
    "Grouping": {
        "TableGroupingPolicy": "CombineCompatibleSchemas"
    }
}
 and SchemaChangePolicy 
{
    "UpdateBehavior": "UPDATE_IN_DATABASE",
    "DeleteBehavior": "DELETE_FROM_DATABASE"
}
. Note that values in the Configuration override values in the SchemaChangePolicy for S3 Targets.

BENCHMARK : Finished writing to Catalog
BENCHMARK : Crawler has finished running and is in state READY
```

Comment: What does your crawler log say in cloud watch. Might also be worth checking if the kms key used for that modified file is the same as the rest and the crawler role has access to that kms key

Comment: @Emerson, I have added the cloud watch log in the post, and the **Manual Fixation** section. I have checked the IAM role for this glue crawler, it has the permission to the S3 bucket. And I do not set up encryption (i.e kms key ??) for this glue crawler

Comment: Can U check if there is a kms key set for the file in s3. If u don’t explicitly set, there might be bucket defaults

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading from or writing to S3 buckets, the bucket name should have aws-glue* prefix for Glue to access the buckets. Assuming you are using the preconfigured “AWSGlueServiceRole” IAM role. You can try by adding prefix aws-glue to the name of the folders

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Check the inline policy of your IAM role. You should have something like that when you specify the bucket:

```
"Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/object*"
]
```

When the crawler didn't work, I instead had the following:

```
"Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/object"
]
```